# How to find the sum of number layer in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 10*10 array. I need to find the sum of all layer. Following figure will clear my question:

[image]

How can i do this easily?

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: yes.. I'm using numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without repeated summation of the same elements and without an intermediate array (just brute-force indexing fun) which works for square `n` by `n` arrays for odd or even `n`:

```
import numpy as np

def sum_shells(a):
    n = len(a)
    no2 = n // 2
    shell_sums = []
    for i in range(no2):
        shell_sums.append(np.sum(a[i,i:n-i]) + np.sum(a[n-i-1,i:n-i]) +
                          np.sum(a[i+1:n-i-1,i]) + np.sum(a[i+1:n-i-1,n-i-1]))
    if n % 2:
        shell_sums.append(a[no2, no2])
    return shell_sums

a = np.array([
  [8, 0, 7, 4, 3, 0, 0, 7, 6, 9],
  [8, 1, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 6, 8, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
  [3, 2, 8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7],
  [6, 7, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 9, 0],
  [8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4],
  [7, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5, 1, 7, 4],
  [6, 8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1],
  [9, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0, 8, 7],
  [2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 5, 0, 3, 1, 8] ])

b = np.array([[9, 5, 8, 6, 5],
              [1, 1, 0, 5, 1],
              [5, 9, 7, 0, 0],
              [7, 4, 7, 5, 1],
              [9, 5, 0, 2, 3] ])
print(sum_shells(a))
print(sum_shells(b))
```

Produces:

```
[170, 122, 85, 62, 17]
[67, 31, 7]
```

Comment: You are actually creating lots of small intermediate arrays... When you do e.g. `sum(a[i,i:n-i] + a[n-i-1,i:n-i])`, numpy allocates a new `n-2*i` item array and fills it with the elementwise sum of your two slices. This is of course easy to avoid, with a probably non-negligible speed up, by summing each slice on its own before adding them together. You should also use `np.sum` instead of the standard library's `sum`.

Comment: @Jaime - you're right, of course: I was a bit careless here. I've edited the suggested code. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add another answer... While the general idea of subtracting inner squares from outer ones is probably the best approach, if you wanted performance none of the implementations presented would do too good, since they keep adding the same numbers over and over. To speed this calculation up, you could use what in image processing is called an integral image:

```
>>> int_arr = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(arr, axis=0), axis=1)
>>> int_arr
array([[  8,   8,  15,  19,  22,  22,  22,  29,  35,  44],
       [ 16,  17,  24,  34,  40,  44,  46,  54,  64,  79],
       [ 24,  30,  46,  62,  76,  80,  82,  91, 104, 119],
       [ 27,  35,  59,  84, 103, 115, 123, 137, 156, 178],
       [ 33,  48,  77, 103, 123, 135, 148, 163, 191, 213],
       [ 41,  65,  98, 129, 158, 177, 190, 205, 233, 259],
       [ 48,  81, 120, 158, 191, 217, 235, 251, 286, 316],
       [ 54,  95, 136, 180, 214, 249, 275, 296, 333, 364],
       [ 63, 105, 147, 194, 235, 276, 310, 331, 376, 414],
       [ 65, 115, 163, 213, 260, 306, 340, 364, 410, 456]])
```

From this helper array you can compute the area of any rectangular subarray adding two entries and subtracting two others, e.g.:

```
>>> np.sum(arr[1:-1, 1:-1])
286
>>> int_arr[-2,-2] + int_arr[0, 0] - int_arr[-2, 0] - int_arr[0, -2]
286
```

With this, you could compute your sums easily as, e.g.:

```
sums = [int_arr[-1, -1]]
top = 0
bot = len(arr) - 2
while top < bot:
    new_sum = (int_arr[bot, bot] + int_arr[top, top] -
               int_arr[top, bot] - int_arr[bot, top])
    sums[-1] -= new_sum
    sums.append(new_sum)
    top += 1
    bot -= 1

>>> sums
[170, 122, 85, 62, 17]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to get the sum of a `(2n)*(2n)` square in the middle, then it is very easy: take the sum of the `(2n)*(2n)` square, then subtract the sum of the `(2n-2)*(2n-2)` square inside it; the difference is the sum of the elements on the border (that is, are in the outer square but not the inner):

```
import numpy

# let x be a 10 * 10 array
x = numpy.array([
  [8, 0, 7, 4, 3, 0, 0, 7, 6, 9],
  [8, 1, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6],
  [8, 5, 9, 6, 8, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
  [3, 2, 8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7],
  [6, 7, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 9, 0],
  [8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4],
  [7, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5, 1, 7, 4],
  [6, 8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1],
  [9, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0, 8, 7],
  [2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 5, 0, 3, 1, 8],
])

for i in xrange(1, 6): # loop with i = 1,...,5
  # find the sum of the (2i)*(2i) square in the middle
  a = numpy.sum(x[5-i:5+i, 5-i:5+i])

  # find the sum of the (2i-2)*(2i-2) square in the middle
  b = numpy.sum(x[6-i:4+i, 6-i:4+i])

  # the difference gives the sum of the elements on the border
  s = a - b
  print s
```

> 17
>   62
>   85
>   122
>   170

Answer (score 2):

The code below calculate each layer and then subtracts the smaller layer from it. It's quite general, and so any array of size N*N should be able to be passed to it, as long as `N` is even (I think).

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[8, 0, 7, 4, 3, 0, 0, 7, 6, 9],
                [8, 1, 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6],
                [8, 5, 9, 6, 8, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
                [3, 2, 8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7],
                [6, 7, 5, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 9, 0],
                [8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0, 4],
                [7, 9, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5, 1, 7, 4],
                [6, 8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1],
                [9, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0, 8, 7],
                [2, 8, 6, 3, 6, 5, 0, 3, 1, 8]])

N = len(arr)

def sum_layer(arr, M, N=N):
    """Function to return the sum of a layer."""
    return arr[M:N-M, M:N-M].sum()

# Each of the layers.
layers = [sum_layer(arr, i) for i in range(N - N//2)]

# Subtract the smaller areas from the larger, to get the margins.
result = [layers[i] - layers[i+1] for i in range(N//2 - 1)]

# Need to add the final, smallest layer on.
result.append(layers[-1])

print(result)
# [170, 122, 85, 62, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. 1st find the sum of whole 10*10 array, then find the sum of inner 9*9 array. Then subtraction is the result of sum of outer layer.

```
for i in range(len(A)/2):
    B = A[1:-1, 1:-1]
    print sum(A)-sum(B)
    A = B
```

A loop will find all sum.

May be there is better way to do this..